# Is there a Linux Equivalent of Macrium Reflect?

Tags: linux, hard-disk, hardware, ssd

I am using dell precision 3520 running ubuntu 18.04 lts. I am trying to replace my HDD with SSD. I would like to have all my data transferred to the new disk. On Windows there is Macrium Reflect to do this (if there is a way of using Macrium in ubuntu, please tell me). How would I do this in linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Clonezilla Live](https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php) is one equivalent of Macrium Reflect and provides a GUI, which may be considered easier than doing the same job with [dd](https://opensource.com/article/18/7/how-use-dd-linux). Both are Open Source, free as in beer.

Answer (score 0):

[StorageCraft's ShadowProtect SPX](https://www.storagecraft.com/supportedLinuxVersions) covers both Windows and Linux systems including Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04. I've used it for years and find it to be both convenient and reliable for Enterprise environments and small networks. Sorry this answer came so late.